# Symfony 3 can't send email test

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm a newbie with Symfony 3 (Symfony generally) 
I want to send an email, just to test my parameters, if everything's going well, but that doesn't work. 
Here my parameters.yml file:

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: learnsymfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: 'personalemail@gmail.com'
secret: 7759e1c20bb67e4ec0fbac5c3a4de22beed3b95d
```

And Here my config.yml code for swiftmailer:

```
transport: gmail
host:      smtp.gmail.com
username:  'personalemail@gmail.com'
password:  'myPassword'
spool: { type: memory }
```

I found this configuration in one question here in the forum, but for my case, that was given an error "Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]" 
Any suggestion please? 
I tried alot of other configurations but nothing works well...
thanks

Comment: If you're using two-step auth, make sure you put your app password and not your Google Password...

Comment: check your config, if you are in dev you have to set swiftermailer: disable_delivery: false to actually send the email, else it doesn't send and you have to check the profilier to see what would have been sent

Comment: @JovanPerovic what's that exactly? I heard it before but no idea...

Comment: @Rooneyl where should I set that exactly? and yes i'm in dev

Comment: Go here: https://www.google.com/landing/2step/. Click "Get started" on the top and login with you Google credentials. The very fist thing on the next page says, in my case: "2-Step Verification is ON since >>some-date<<"

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem today and got resolved by following [how to send email in Symfony](https://github.com/dancostinel/symfony-email)
After following these steps don't forget to import these in your default controller:

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route as Route;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

And make sure your email and password which you are using "#app/config/parameters.yml" are correct.